# Minimizar tamaño documento en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

estoy haciendo un programa para el que necesito almacenar documentos escaneados. El problema es que ocupan mucho espacio en la base de datos y necesito minimizar el tamaño de estos a la hora de guardarlos.

El campo donde guardo los archivos se llama "documento" y es de tipo varbinary(max).

He usado esta consulta SQL para calcular cuánto ocupan más o menos los archivos y ocupan unos 4MB cada archivo de 1 página.

```
USE databaseName;  
GO

SELECT (total_log_size_in_bytes - used_log_space_in_bytes)*1.0/1024/1024 AS [free log space in MB]  
FROM sys.dm_db_log_space_usage;
```

¿Sabéis alguna forma de reducir el tamaño? También si sabéis otra forma de calcular el tamaño que ocupa el registro en la base de datos lo agradecería, ya que de esta forma no puedo calcularlo bien.

Uso SQL Server.

Comment: No lo guardes en la base de datos. Guarda el archivo en un servidor de archivos y guarda la ruta en la base de datos.

Comment: @LuisCazares gracias por la sugerencia, pero me han pedido que guarde los archivos en la propia base de datos.

Comment: ¿Quién te lo ha pedido? ¿Están conscientes del costo que representará al manejar los respaldos y en general de la administración de la base de datos? Si lo saben y están dispuesto a enfrentarse a los problemas que puede traer, no necesitas reducir el tamaño de los archivos (y SQL Server no puede hacer mucho con eso).

Comment: @LuisCazares me  dijeron que para que la base de datos no ocupara tanto espacio, tenía que reducir el tamaño de los archivos. Pero tengo que guardarlos ahí, por lo que supongo que si tendrán la capacidad de manejarlo.

Comment: Si son escaneos, en que formato almacenas los ficheros, con ese peso, supongo que estarán en jpg ?. o están en pdf

Comment: @el.trasgu están en pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existen muchas formas de comprimir archivos antes de que lleguen a la base de datos. Sin embargo, una vez que llegan a la base de datos, lo único que se recomienda hacer es usar la compresión por filas que está disponible en SQL Server 2016 SP1 en adelante para todas las ediciones y en versiones anteriores para las ediciones Enterprise.

Para activarlo, se puede usar el siguiente formato.

```
ALTER TABLE MiTabla REBUILD PARTITION = ALL  
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW);   
GO
```

Obviamente, hay que cambiar el nombre de la tabla. También es importante que los archivos no sean parte de ningún índice porque se duplicaría la información.

Comment: Con este método se ha reducido el tamaño a la mitad, ¡muchas gracias!